# Possible to grep and modify/touch the file modification date?

Tags: linux

I am using the following to find all instances of a string in a number of files and delete the line where they are found.

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -xdev -type f -exec sed -i '/teststring/Id' {} \;
```

I don't want to change the date the file was modified because that impacts on the order that the files are shown in an unrelated application. So I was thinking I could grab the date before executing sed, then touch the file and replace the old modify date at the end of the command. I want to have it all in one command integrated with the above if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following command:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -xdev -type f -exec sed -i.bak '/teststring/Id' {} \; -exec touch -r {}.bak {} \; -exec rm {}.bak \;
```

The `find` command executes three steps for each file found:

1. `sed` changes the file and creates a backup of the original file (with a `.bak` extension)
2. `touch` sets the timestamp of the new file to be the same as the backup
3. `rm` deletes the backup

Comment: dogbane, does this leave .bak files around the file system? Or do they all get deleted after?

Comment: I have 3 variations (delete all lines delete string, and replace string) I am using and it seems like they failed for some reason and left .bak files, may I ask you to take a look at them?

Comment: I think it has something to do with find starting from " . " directory. I am changing it to a specific starting folder e.g " / ". and that causes it to fail. Any idea why?

Comment: it works for me. Please create a better example which shows your problem.

Comment: I have worked out that it is a problem with the sed delimiter and not related to your answer. I have posted a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13865070/sed-delimiter-not-playing-nice-with-grep which you may be able to help with anyway? Thank you

Comment: On my RedHat system I needed to quote "{}.bak" or the result comes out as ".bak". But the unquoted {} seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

```
for file in $(find . -maxdepth 1 -xdev -type f )
do
   mod_time=$(stat --format=%y $file)
   perl -wpl -i -e 's!teststring!!' $file
   touch -d ''$mod_time'' $file
```

done

Comment: Fails if filenames contain spaces. `:-(`.